# DB2 Timestamp Query shows differetn value in excel

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I am using c#, with DB2, a query

```
SELECT current timestamp FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

shows correct value in Toad, but throgh code, gets value formatted in `DD/MM/YY HH:MM` format when I show it in excel.

Comment: this is the formate used by excel to display date formate

Comment: you have edited and delete excel word from your question ??
in which you are getting value through code??

Comment: In Excel. Sorry if it got deleted from question.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp value is the same*, it's just how it's being displayed in Excel.  You can change the formatting in Excel to display the value as it shows in DB2 if you'd like.

Note:  A DB2 timestamp is accurate to microseconds, but Excel only supports milliseconds.  So you will lose a little precision.

Comment: I have checked that option of formatting cells. Its the wrong value that is coming from DB.

Comment: Can you provide some query results that you get from Toad and your c# app?

Comment: @buffer_overflow  if you are getting values, although in different format, but if you are getting date only then it means DB is currect and giving date only..
if you need to give it so display then you need to put to_char() [in oracle, you have to find out simlar function in DB2] to convert date value in string/varchar with desired formate

Comment: @pratik garg I am getting value in DD/MM/YY HH:MM format. I want that value to be as its is returned by DB2 for timestamp, i.e. micro-second accuracy.

Comment: I commented the solution for this ...
please check for to_char or respective function in DB2 and how to use it, you will get many formates, so by this you have to take micro sec also..